# getting error at a ionic build

Tags: ionic-framework, compiler-errors

[[image: I am stuck please help me.I am not able to build apk]

I am getting error what shown in image

**not able to build**

Comment: You should copy/paste the error instead of screenshoting it. It would be easier for search purpose.

Comment: Looks like it might be a permission issue, have you tried running it as admin from the command prompt?

Comment: it was problem with insight_cordova permission .json .now solved

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough details to answer your question, still I wanna give it a try.

From docs have you done?

-Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the location of your JDK installation

-Set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the location of your Android SDK installation

-It is also recommended that you add the Android SDK's tools and platform-tools directories to your PATH

[ref](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

HTH! Thanks.